# sensing geolocation using google maps

Tags: javascript, google-api

I am creating a functionality to sense the users geolocation using google api but i am having a problem that although the code seems to be alright the output is not showing i.e i am getting nothing as my location. Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Geolocation</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <A href = "#" id = "get_location">Get Location</A>
    <DIV id = "map">
        <IFRAME id = "google_map" width = "400" height = "350" frameborder = "0" scrolling = "no" marginheight = "0" marginwidth = "0"  src = "https://maps.google.co.in?output=embed"></IFRAME>
    </DIV>
    <SCRIPT type = "text/javascript">
        var getter = function(pos) {
            var user_lattitude = pos.coords.lattitude;
            var user_longitude = pos.coords.longitude;
            var user_coordinates = user_lattitude + ',' + user_longitude;
            document.getElementById('google_map').setAttribute('src' , 'https://maps.google.co.in/?q=' + user_coordinates + '&z=60&output=embed');
        }
        document.getElementById('get_location').onclick = function() {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getter);
            return false;
        }
    </SCRIPT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've just spelt latitude wrong.

```
pos.coords.lattitude ;
```

It should only have 1 t. If you change that your above code will work.